# Original DECUS version of Sumer in FOCAL?

Tags: dec

I was sure I had a copy of Diamont's Sumer in FOCAL, but now I can't find a trace of it on my machines or online.

Does anyone have a copy of the original code?

Comment: Might it be in a DECUS archive?  I think the Internet Archive has one.

Comment: Ahh, looking for "DECUS catalog" turns up the fact that DEC calls this program "f0005.fc", and thus the failure to find it online. Googling that name instead immediately turns it up.